# Chart.JS - Wrong Y axis

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I've added two y-axes to my Chart.JS, but I believe both of the line curves are being referenced only by the left axis. Check the image below, where the tooltip is showing the 2019 point. Both, red and blue lines are referenced by the left axis. I would like to one of them to be referenced by the right axis. [image]

```js
                // set default to straight lines - no curves
                Chart.defaults.global.elements.line.tension = 0.5;
                // set default no fill beneath the line
                Chart.defaults.global.elements.line.fill = false;

                // stacked bar with 2 unstacked lines - nope
                var barChartData = {
                labels: ['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019'],
                datasets: [{
                    type: 'line',
                    label: 'Red',
                    id: "y-axis-0",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(51,51,51,0.5)",
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
                    data: [1500, 2600, 4700, 5800]
                },{
                    type: 'line',
                    label: 'Red Top',
                    id: "y-axis-0",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)",
                    borderColor: "transparent",
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    fill: 0,
                    tension: 0.5,
                    data: [1600, 2700, 4800, 5900]
                },{
                    type: 'line',
                    label: 'Red Bottom',
                    id: "y-axis-0",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)",
                    borderColor: "transparent",
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    fill: 0,
                    tension: 0.5,
                    data: [1400, 2500, 4600, 5700]
                }, {
                    type: 'line',
                    label: 'Blue',
                    id: "y-axis-1",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(44, 130, 201, 1)",
                    data: [5000, 3000, 1000, 0]
                }, {
                    type: 'line',
                    label: 'Blue Top',
                    id: "y-axis-1",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(44, 130, 201, 0.3)",
                    borderColor: "transparent",
                    pointRadius: 0.5,
                    fill: 3,
                    tension: 0,
                    data: [5100, 3100, 1100, 100]
                }, {
                    type: 'line',
                    label: 'Blue Bottom',
                    id: "y-axis-1",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(44, 130, 201, 0.3)",
                    borderColor: "transparent",
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    fill: 3,
                    tension: 0.5,
                    data: [4900, 2900, 900, 0]
                }
                ]
                };


                var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
                // allocate and initialize a chart
                var ch = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartData,
                options: {
                    title: {
                    display: false,
                    text: "Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked"
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                    mode: 'label'
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: false,
                        position: "left",
                        id: "y-axis-0",
                        ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Left'
                        },
                    }, {
                        stacked: false,
                        position: "right",
                        id: "y-axis-1",
                        ticks: {
                            min: -1000,
                            max: 8000,
                            stepSize: 1000,
                            beginAtZero: true,
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Right'
                        },
                    }, ]
                    },
                    legend: {
                    display: false,
                    },
                }
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myChart" width="600px" height="400px"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by replacing `id` with `yAxisID` at datasets.